# How to change the props of a component using hooks in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

```
import {useState} from "react";
import Weather from "./Weather";
import Forecast from "./Forecast";

const Home = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
  
  return (
    <>
      <a onClick={setIndex(1)}>Change</a>
      <Weather index={index} />
      <Forecast index={index}/>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I am trying to update the index using an anchor or link. The error shows too many re-renders. Please be kind enough to explain this problem to me.

Comment: You have a typo. `onClick={setIndex(1)}` should be `onClick={() => setIndex(1)}` — essentially you're constantly calling `setIndex` on every render, which causes a render.